# Creating a SQL Query to list Job failures within a 24hr period

Tags: sql-server, database, android-activity, jobs, database-backups

I need help creating a SQL Query against 'Job Activies' for roughtly 5/10 Jobs on diff SQL Servers. Basically I need to produce a list as below, save me going into the Job Activity each time that shows the below Jobs, any starting with the name 'MAINTENANCE - BACKUP..' ideally, then the following Columns - Enabled/Status/Last Run Outcome/Last Run/Next Run

[image]

Once I can assitain which Jobs are Enabled, have Succeeded etc. I would then check the History of each Job within the 24hr period, making a note of the time of each Failure and the Error/Reason why. I have multiple Queries off the Internet which kind of give me the details I'm looking for, but I'm unsure on how to re-order the code/query and just pick out what I need specifically.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code showing exactly what you're having trouble with?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/Mk4Uv7CN) & [link](http://pastebin.com/QwiBBMW1) are the two sets of code I've been playing about with

Comment: Put yourself on the notification list for when the job fails.  Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've asked the DBA, but have a feeling even if I get these alerts, I'll still need to drum up an Excel document with the main Status and Failures from the History. May end up having to got hrough emails instead of the SQL DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view, from this code and select from it via the dates:

```
SELECT   Job.instance_id
    ,SysJobs.job_id
    ,SysJobs.name as 'JOB_NAME'
    ,SysJobSteps.step_name as 'STEP_NAME'
    ,Job.run_status
    ,Job.sql_message_id
    ,Job.sql_severity
    ,Job.message
    ,Job.exec_date
    ,Job.run_duration
    ,Job.server
    ,SysJobSteps.output_file_name
FROM    (SELECT Instance.instance_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.job_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.sql_message_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.sql_severity
    ,DBSysJobHistory.message
    ,(CASE DBSysJobHistory.run_status
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress'
    END) as run_status
    ,((SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '/'
    + SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2) + '/'
    + SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4) + ' '
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS varchar)))
    + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 1, 2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)))
    + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 3, 2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time as varchar)))
    + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 5, 2))) AS 'exec_date'
    ,DBSysJobHistory.run_duration
    ,DBSysJobHistory.retries_attempted
    ,DBSysJobHistory.server
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
    JOIN (SELECT DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ,MAX(DBSysJobHistory.instance_id) as instance_id
        FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
        GROUP BY DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ) AS Instance ON DBSysJobHistory.instance_id = Instance.instance_id
    WHERE DBSysJobHistory.run_status <> 1
    ) AS Job
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs SysJobs
   ON (Job.job_id = SysJobs.job_id)
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps SysJobSteps
   ON (Job.job_id = SysJobSteps.job_id AND Job.step_id = SysJobSteps.step_id)
```

Comment: This Query seems to work really well! II have removed some parts that aren't required (may be some redundant code still there). Is there a way to only show Job's withthe Job Name starting with 'MAINTENANCE - BACKUP' and also add the additional Colums -

Comment: Sorry I hadn't finished the above comment... This Query seems to work really well! I'm getting a bit confused though, as I ideally need one Query to show me the current Job Activity status, then another to go into the Job History for each Activity and check for any Failures over the past 24hrs. This Query seems to be for the 2nd part, which is great! I have removed some parts that aren't required (may be some redundant code still in there). Is there a way to only show Job's with the Job Name starting with the text 'MAINTENANCE - BACKUP'. I don't need this Part amending as it seems to work fine

Comment: Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/2AMk3CWy) to my amended code. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the last 24 hours of job details that you needed... or it'll get your started anyway.

```
select
    j.name as JobName,
    j.enabled,
    j.date_created,
    a.start_execution_date,
    a.stop_execution_date,
    a.next_scheduled_run_date,
    h.run_date,
    h.run_time,
    case
        when h.run_status = 0 then 'Failed'
        when h.run_status = 1 then 'Succeeded'
        when h.run_status = 2 then 'Retry'
        when h.run_status = 3 then 'Canceled'
    end as LastRunOutcome
from 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a on
    a.job_id = j.job_id
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h on
    h.job_id = j.job_id
    inner join
    (select job_id, max(run_date) dt
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    group by job_id) h2 on h2.job_id = h.job_id and h2.dt = h.run_date
where
    cast(a.start_execution_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: This query gives me the message;

Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: It is SQL Server, but I only have access to the DB via Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: Not sure what version you have but change the bottom line from cast to convert like so.... convert(date,a.start_execution_date) = convert(date, getdate())

Comment: I have tried this, but I'm still given the same message unfortunatly. If I remove the bottom 2 lines, from 'where' onwards, the query works, but is producing a list over a few hundread results, seems to be too much info. Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Well that makes zero sense.

Comment: I get some results, but from years ago, about 20,000+ worth of old Job History.

Comment: Well yes because you removed the date filter which was the bottom line. The bottom like is limiting the data for jobs executed on the day you run it.

Comment: I see, all new to me this. Will have to have a play around and Google to try get what I'm after. I basically need a Query to show me the data captured fromt he Activity on my initial Question, then another to check Job Failures. The other Query above actually excluded all data if no Failures, I still need to report the status of all 6 jobs :/ need DB admin to go through it with me ideally